# How to create table manually or use postgres partition when using dbt?

Tags: database, postgresql, dbt

I want to insert data into a partitioned table using dbt, but found no support for dbt postgres partition.

By another way, i create table and partition in pre_hook, but got the error "relation 'download_counts_p' already exists" when dbt run

Are there any suggestions ? Here is my SQL and pre_hook config

```html
{{ config(
    materialized = 'table',
    indexes = [ ],
    pre_hook=[
        'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "download_counts_p" (
                                              "channel_id" int8 NOT NULL,
                                              "product_id" int8 NOT NULL,
                                              "country_code" text NOT NULL,
                                              "year" int2  NULL,
                                              "month" int2 NOT NULL,
                                              "count" int8 NOT NULL,
                                              "count" int8 NOT NULL,
                                              "months" int8 NOT NULL
                                         ) partition by list(country_code)',
        "DO $$
    Declare unique_country_code varchar;
    BEGIN
        FOR unique_country_code IN
            SELECT country_code as unique_country_code FROM download_counts group by country_code

            LOOP
                EXECUTE  format('create table IF NOT EXISTS download_counts_p_%s partition of download_counts_p for values in (''%s'')', upper(unique_country_code), unique_country_code);
            END LOOP;
    END; $$;"]
)}}


select 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different things going on here.

1. You are correct that dbt's postgres adapter [does not currently support](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/postgres-configs) a config for partitioned tables. The solution here is to create a [new materialization](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/guides/creating-new-materializations) that inserts the extra DDL you need. You don't want to be manually writing DDL in dbt -- this is considered a big antipattern. You may also want to open an issue in dbt-core (where the postgres adapter code lives) to make a feature request
2. Your `FOR ... LOOP ... END LOOP` hook should really be written as its own model, using a jinja loop. You can return data to the jinja context using the [`run_query`](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/run_query) macro. There is an example toward the bottom of that page that fetches the query results into the jinja context and then loops over them with `{% for payment_method in results_list %}`

Answer (score -2):

In DBT DDL table creation is automatically done and running pre-hook or post-hook will not be help since PostgreSQL do not allow alter the table to have partition by clause.

Instead of pre_hook blocks -which also need to be done for every module-. The create table statement from DBT postgres can be modified to handle table partition creation. Both range and list types are supported by this solution.

as an example of PostgreSQL DDL statement

```
            CREATE TABLE measurement (
                city_id         int not null,
                logdate         date not null,
                peaktemp        int,
                unitsales       int
            ) PARTITION BY RANGE (logdate);
```

after this DDL is modified to have the PARTITION BY clause then partitions can be created and attached

Apply the adaptation

1- find the postgres dbt adapter in your project, normally path like:

```
venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/dbt/include/postgres/macros/adapters.sql
```

2- modify the content of `postgres__create_table_as` macro to be as below:

```
{% macro postgres__create_table_as(temporary, relation, sql) -%}
{%- set unlogged = config.get(‘unlogged’, default=false) -%}
{%- set sql_header = config.get(‘sql_header’, none) -%}

{%- set fields_string = config.get(‘fields_string’, none) -%}

{%- set partition_type = config.get(‘partition_type’, none) -%}
{%- set partition_column = config.get(‘partition_column’, none) -%}

{%- set partition_range_start_end = config.get(‘partition_range_start_end’, none) -%}
{%- set partition_list_values = config.get(‘partition_list_values’, none) -%}

{%- set is_partition = partition_type is not none -%}

{{ sql_header if sql_header is not none }}

create {% if temporary -%}
temporary
{%- elif unlogged -%}
unlogged
{%- endif %} table {{ relation }}
as (
{{ sql }}
{% if is_partition and not temporary %}
limit 0
{% endif %}
);

{% if is_partition and not temporary %}

{%- set relation_str=relation -%}
{%- set relation_str -%}
{{ relation_str|string|replace(‘“‘, ‘’) }}
{%- endset -%}

{%- set relation_str2-%}{{relation_str}}_tmp4part{%- endset -%}
{%- set relation_str2-%}”{{relation_str2|replace(‘.’,’”.”’)}}”{%- endset -%}

CREATE TABLE {{relation_str2}} ( like {{ relation }} including all) PARTITION BY {{ partition_type }} ({{ partition_column }});
DROP TABLE {{ relation }};
CREATE TABLE {{ relation }} ( like {{relation_str2}} including all ) PARTITION BY {{ partition_type }} ({{ partition_column }});
DROP TABLE {{relation_str2}};

{% if partition_type|lower == ‘range’ %}
{% for rng in partition_range_start_end %}
{% set start = rng[0] %}
{% set end = rng[1] %}
{%- set table4part-%}{{relation_str}}_{{loop.index}} {%- endset -%}
{%- set table4part-%}”{{table4part|replace(‘.’,’”.”’)}}” {%- endset -%}
CREATE TABLE {{table4part}} PARTITION OF {{ relation }} FOR VALUES FROM (‘{{start}}’) TO (‘{{end}}’);
{% endfor %}
{% elif partition_type|lower == ‘list’ %}
{% for val in partition_list_values.split(‘,’) %}
{%- set table4part-%}{{relation_str}}_{{loop.index}} {%- endset -%}
{%- set table4part-%}”{{table4part|replace(‘.’,’”.”’)}}” {%- endset -%}
CREATE TABLE {{table4part}} PARTITION OF {{ relation }} FOR VALUES IN ({{val}});
{% endfor %}
{%- endif %}

{# INSERT DATA #}
insert into {{ relation }} (
{{ sql }}
);
{% endif %}

{%- endmacro %}
```

3- Choose the partitioning list in the module to be created like below for example:

```
            {%- set partition_type = ‘LIST’ -%}
            {%- set partition_column = ‘level’ -%}
            {%- set partition_list_values=’1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51'-%}

            {{
            config(
            materialized=’incremental’,
            partition_type=partition_type,
            partition_column=partition_column,
            partition_list_values=partition_list_values,
            unique_key=[‘col1’,’col2’]
            )
            }}
```

Reference and More details https://medium.com/@fmohammad_91999/postgresql-table-partitioning-in-dbt-6d6ed82e90ca